# Send private secret code to customer via email

Tags: email, security

My company's online eCommerce product has a requirement to send customer's secret PIN number via email. Any thoughts on the idea itself from a security perspective. Also please share how a secure email can be sent.

Just to elabore a bit more, this online product has over 100K customers as of now, and sales team thinks that we have a potenial of growing up customer base to over 1 million. Also we are using ASP.NET.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636363/using-ssl-tls-when-sending-an-email-from-php/7636426#7636426.  In short, you cannot send an email securely without implementing PGP encryption and exchanging encryption keys with your recipients.

Comment: BTW I have read some information at similar question answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770974/best-practice-to-send-secure-information-over-e-mail, I am looking more details on how exactly each step can be accomplished.

Comment: Be aware that key management and encryption is generally far beyond the technical abilities of most users (even technical ones). That's one of the reasons hardly anyone other than crypto-privacy enthusiasts uses the system today. And if they are using web mail (yahoo, gmail, hotmail, whatever), the chances of having support of encryption and key management are very slim.

Comment: That's exactly what bothering me from CanSpice answer below. Because most of our clients are regular Joe Blo using gmail, hotmail etc and therefore I was not sure how practical the solution could be where we use public keys for each one of the customer.

Comment: It's impractical beyond consideration, I'm afraid.  When banks, health, or governmental agencies need to transmit a PIN or SSN card (in my experience), they do so in a secure envelope through snail mail. If you don't receive the PIN it is assumed compromised and a new one is issued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you're going to do this securely is if you encrypt the email. You would do this with something like [OpenPGP](http://www.openpgp.org/). This requires your company to store the public key of every one of your customers, however, in order to send the encrypted email to your customers.

Comment: Just added more clarification in questions above. Considering the number of clients, is it practical to store public key for each customer for this scenario?

Comment: If you want to send sensitive information over email, then you're going to have to store the public key for each customer. There's no getting around that. And as for its practicality, that depends on you. Anything is practical if you throw enough resources at it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply CanSpice but please see Michael's comment. I think that is the scenario where users are using web email service like gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc. That I think make using your solution impractical. Am  I wrong?

Comment: You said you wanted to send email securely. That means you need to encrypt the email, regardless of how practical that is. If you want to transmit information securely to the customer, you have them login to a website where they have some kind of message box. Make sure everything's done over HTTPS and then you've solved your "get the PIN to the customer securely" problem without having to send them an encrypted email.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can post it up on an HTTPS application. They can log in to their account to retrieve it.

Comment: Of course application will be on HTTPS, however, this question is about registering a user first time. At that point we are not sure login user is really who what (s)he is caliming as.

Comment: oh, I see. Your question didn't make it clear that this was a process to get registered for first using your app. Sending it over a second completely independent channel such as SMS, phone or post is probably your best bet, if it is in any way practical.